# How to search in Protobuf repeated fields?

Tags: c#, protobuf-csharp-port

It's the first time im working with protobuf, and I wonder if there is any way to get access to a certain item inside a Repeated Field.

I created a method that will iterate through all the items, check an item field, and return it (i cannot return the pointer to it :( ).

```
public Appearance findItem(int itemID) {
  foreach (Appearance item in appearances.Object) {
    if (item.Id == itemID) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It seems there is no find method to use some lambda expressions.

Is there any other way to achieve this? It would be perfect if i could hav pointer to the item, not a copy of it, so if i change it, i can write the complete repeated field directly.

Comment: I've provided an answer using LINQ - if that doesn't work for you, please provide a [mcve] so we can help you in a more concrete way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be perfect if i could hav pointer to the item, not a copy of it, so if i change it, i can write the complete repeated field directly.

You can't do that, but you could return the *index* of the element instead. Given that repeated fields implement `IEnumerable<T>`, you should be able to use LINQ easily enough. For example:

```
// index is an "int?" with a value of null if no items matched the query
var index = repeatedField
    // You could use tuples here if you're using C# 7. That would be more efficient.
    .Select((value, index) => new { value, (int?) index })
    // This is whatever condition you want
    .Where(pair => pair.value.SomeField == "foo")
    .Select(pair => pair.index)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hello Daisy, Thanks for replying. I tried this solution but the compilers complains about the Select clause. The RepeatedField class is this one from google Docs:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-

Inheritance: Inherits from: IList< T >, IList, Google.Protobuf.IDeepCloneable< T >, IEquatable< RepeatedField< T >>

Comment: @Vysius: What exactly do you mean by "the compilers complain"? A precise error message would make it easier to help you - as would a [mcve] so that we could easily test this for ourselves. (Do you have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`, for example?)

Comment: 2 years later...but you'll need "using System.Linq;" to get to the all the Linq methods

Comment: @JohnnyWu: Yes, but I'd generally expect C# developers to be aware of that given a preamble of "you should be able to use LINQ easily enough".